# Javascript: No access to div added in another script

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an online compiler using Django. I have used [this](http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm) plugin to add number lines to my `textarea` so that it will look more like my text editor.

This plugin adds `div`s as line numbers and can also highlight line number by adding `lineselect` class to `div`. So I decided to use that feature to highlight line numbers where compile error is met.

The problem is that plugin dynamically adds `div`s when user scrolls `textarea`. I can't highlight line numbers past the lines currently shown. I tried to scroll down to bottom before trying to highlight line numbers but it didn't work.

My script is near the end. I also can't move my script to separate `.js` file since in that case it can't access elements added by Django conditionals.

**compile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        {% load static  from staticfiles %}
        <link href = {% static "styles/recompile_style.css" %} type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = {% static "scripts/jquery-linedtextarea.js" %}></script>  <!-- plugin itself -->
        <script src = {% static "scripts/tabIndent.js" %}></script> <!-- plugin for inserting tab character when pressing tab -->
        <title>OCD</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "left-column-div">
            <div id = "compile-div">
                <form id = "compile" name = "Compile" action = "/comp_old/" method = "post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for = "c">C</label>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "language" value = "c" {% if language == "c" %}checked{% endif %}></br>
                    <label for = "c++">C++</label>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "language" value = "c++" {% if language == "c++" %}checked{% endif %}></br>

                    <label>Source Code:</label></br>


                    <!-- this text area is where i try to highlight (id = "code") -->
                    <textarea rows = "15" cols = "70" class = "lined" id = "code" name = "code" placeholder = "Your code">{{ code }}</textarea></br></br>
                    <!-- ........................................................ -->


                    <label>Input File:</label></br>
                    <textarea rows = "15" cols = "70" class = "lined" name = "inp" placeholder = "Your input (if needed)">{{ inp }}</textarea></br>
                    <label>Flags:</label></br>
                    <input type = "text" size = "50" name = "flags" placeholder = "Flags for compiler (if needed)" value = {{ flags }}></br>
                    <button id = "compile-button" class = "subm-button" name = "recompile" type = "submit" style = "float: left">Recompile</button>
                    {% if run_access %}
                    <button id = "compile-button" class = "subm-button" name = "run" type = "submit" style = "float: left">Run</button>
                    {% endif %}<p style = "float: left;margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px"> or </p>
                    <input type = "button" class = "subm-button" id = "open-file" name = "open-file" value = "Open file" style = "float: left"><input type = "file" id = "code_file"><br><br>
                    <script>
                        function readSingleFile(e) {
                            var file = e.target.files[0];
                            if (!file) {
                                return;
                            }
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function(e) {
                                var contents = e.target.result;
                                displayContents(contents);
                            };
                            reader.readAsText(file);
                        }

                        function displayContents(contents) {
                            var element = document.getElementById('code');
                            element.innerHTML = contents;
                        }

                        var button = document.getElementById ("open-file");
                        if (button)
                        {
                            button.onclick = function()
                            {
                                var element = document.getElementById ("code_file");
                                if (element)
                                {
                                    element.addEventListener ("change", readSingleFile, false);
                                    element.click();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                </form>
                {% if no_language_error %}
                <p>Please select language</p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if no_code_error %}
                <p>Please write code</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            tabIndent.renderAll();
        </script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".lined").linedtextarea(
                {selectedClass: 'lineselect'}
            );
        });
        </script>
        <div id = "right-column-div">
            <div id = "escape-div">
                {% if response %}
                <textarea id = "output-text" rows = "15" cols = "60" name = "response" readonly = "">{{ response }}</textarea>
                {% if debug_access %}
                <form id = "debug" name = "DebugButton" action = "/comp_debug/" method = "post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button name = "debug" type = "submit">Debug</button>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
                <script>



                    /*my script where i try to highlight according to line numbers given by compiler errors*/
                    $(document).ready (function() {
                        var errText = document.getElementById ("output-text");
                        if (errText != null)
                        {
                            var reset = document.getElementsByClassName ("lineno lineselect");
                            for (var i = 0; i < reset.length; ++i)
                            {
                                reset[i].className = "lineno";
                            }
                            var errors = errText.innerHTML;
                            var indices = [];
                            var pos = 0;
                            var next = -1;
                            while (pos != -1) {
                                pos = errors.indexOf ("Position", next + 1);
                                if (pos != -1)
                                {
                                    indices.push (pos);
                                }
                                next = pos;
                            }
                            var nlines = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i)
                            {
                                var index = indices[i];
                                for (var j = indices[i]; errors.charAt (j) != ":"; ++j)
                                {
                                    ++index;
                                }
                                index += 2;
                                var nline = "";
                                for (var j = index; errors.charAt (j) != "/"; ++j)
                                {
                                    nline += errors.charAt (j);
                                }
                                nlines.push (nline);
                            }


                            /* nlines is an array of number lines, i try to highlight here by assigning lineselect class */
                            for (var i = 0; i < nlines.length; ++i)
                            {
                                var obj = document.getElementById ("code");
                                if (obj)
                                {
                                    obj.scrollTop = 99999; /* tried to scroll to bottom before highlighting */
                                    var temp = document.getElementById (nlines[i]); /* doesn't see elements below 16 lines */
                                    if (temp)
                                    {
                                        console.log (temp);
                                        if (obj)
                                        {
                                            temp.className = "lineno lineselect";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }




                        }
                    });
                </script>




                {% endif %}
                {% if no_language_error %}
                <p>Please select language</p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if no_code_error %}
                <p>Please write code</p>
                {% endif %}
                <form id = "return-to-files" name = "ReturnToFiles" action = "/comp_files/" method = "post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button class = "subm-button" id = "return" name = "return" type = "submit">Return to files</button>
                </form>
                <br><br>
                <form id = "logout-button" name = "LogoutButton" action = "/comp_logout/" method = "post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <p>Or</p><button id = "signup_button" class = "subm-button" name = "logout" type = "submit">Logout</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a _lot_ of code/html in your question.  Are you sure you can't reduce the problem to a smaller subset?  People will be more inclined to help if the question is a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Refering to the [plugin](http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm) you gave you can alter it to support more than one line.
change line 44:

```
if (lineNo == opts.selectedLine)
```

to

```
if (lineNo in opts.selectedLine)
```

And init it with

```
linedtextarea({selectedLine:[1,2,3]});
```